# Unable to Send FCM Notification using PHP When app is closed

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, notifications, push

i am using the following php code to send push notifications using Firebase.

I have received notification on Android app successfully if app is opened, but in case if app is closed, then unable to receive notification. But echo display result success.

Is there any changes required in php code?
Anybody, Have an idea?

Here is my PHP code :-

```
function send_notification($token,$title,$desc){
    $msg = array
                (
                'body'  => $desc,
                'title' => $title,
                'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
                );
                $fields = array
                (
                'to'        => $token,
                 'data' => $msg     
                );
                $headers = array
                (
                'Authorization: key=AIzaSyBP9nF9ntawf_sirR9c2eQ0CQUHTVaBpRs',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    #Echo Result Of FireBase Server
    $new_result = json_decode($result);
    echo($result);
}
```

**FCM Token :** dvbsfdkjNH8:APA91bGfvS61gL2XBCq4p0kHOJAjG-ReWpZWO4oWHHflV-baFpSsjm4FjBQCS8dWs_vpbvXJJr7yvOuEmg7rAWNsZfL2r3C0WKrib2dDZSzKZNXaFkHHifYjSvCMntD2bUveovkcidHS

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is fine. This needs to be handled from the app side.
You need to check the FCM intent listner.

An app developer would help you better in this.